# Is webgl MAX_VERTEX_ATTRIBS defined per shader or is it defined as a global limit for the whole program?

Tags: webgl

It's not clear to me from the definitions I am seeing online whether the limit for attributes is on a per shader basis or if it refers to the total limit of attributes allowed in the entire program?

Please advise

Answer (score 1):

It's the max limit any one shader can use. In other words if it returns 8 then every vertex shader can use up to 8 attributes. Shader 1 can use 8 attributes, Shader 2 can use 8 attritutes, Shader 3 can use 8 attributes.

A [visual picture](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/resources/webgl-state-diagram.html) might help

Comment: The "visual picture" is very intuitive. Thanks!