# WebGL trouble drawing two different 3d objects

Tags: shader, webgl

In this WebGL code, it's meant to draw 3 3d monkeys, and 1 3d floor/plane.

But whenever I create a buffer for that one floor shader program, it breaks the monkey shader program. So instead of rendering 3 monkeys, and no floor, it renders no monkeys and no floor.

I commented the code that breaks the program as PROBLEM CODE

Here is the code

var RunDemo = function (vertexShaderText, fragmentShaderText, floorVertexShaderText, floorFragmentShaderText,  SusanImage, SusanModel) {
console.log('This is working');
model = SusanModel;

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('game-surface');
gl = canvas.getContext('webgl');
    model = SusanModel;

if (!gl) {
    console.log('WebGL not supported, falling back on experimental-webgl');
    gl = canvas.getContext('experimental-webgl');
}

if (!gl) {
    alert('Your browser does not support WebGL');
}

gl.clearColor(0.75, 0.85, 0.8, 1.0);
gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);
gl.enable(gl.CULL_FACE);
gl.frontFace(gl.CCW);
gl.cullFace(gl.BACK);

// ------------- Create shaders -------------
var vertexShader = gl.createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
var fragmentShader = gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
var floorVertexShader = gl.createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
var floorFragmentShader = gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);


gl.shaderSource(vertexShader, vertexShaderText);
gl.shaderSource(fragmentShader, fragmentShaderText);
gl.shaderSource(floorVertexShader, floorVertexShaderText);
gl.shaderSource(floorFragmentShader, floorFragmentShaderText);

compileShader('vertex', vertexShader);
compileShader('fragment', fragmentShader);
compileShader('vertex', floorVertexShader);
compileShader('fragment', floorFragmentShader);

var mainShaderProgram = gl.createProgram();
gl.attachShader(mainShaderProgram, vertexShader);
gl.attachShader(mainShaderProgram, fragmentShader);
linkProgram(mainShaderProgram);

var floorShaderProgram = gl.createProgram();
gl.attachShader(floorShaderProgram, floorVertexShader);
gl.attachShader(floorShaderProgram, floorFragmentShader);
linkProgram(floorShaderProgram);

// Create buffer for "susan"
var susanVertices = SusanModel.meshes[0].vertices;
var susanIndices = [].concat.apply([], SusanModel.meshes[0].faces);
var susanTexCoords = SusanModel.meshes[0].texturecoords[0];
var susanNormals = SusanModel.meshes[0].normals;

var susanPosVertexBufferObject = gl.createBuffer();
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, susanPosVertexBufferObject);
gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(susanVertices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

var susanTexCoordVertexBufferObject = gl.createBuffer();
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, susanTexCoordVertexBufferObject);
gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(susanTexCoords), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

var susanIndexBufferObject = gl.createBuffer();
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, susanIndexBufferObject);
gl.bufferData(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, new Uint16Array(susanIndices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

var susanNormalBufferObject = gl.createBuffer();
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, susanNormalBufferObject);
gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(susanNormals), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

// Setup attributes for "susan"
gl.useProgram(mainShaderProgram);

var positionAttribLocationSusan = gl.getAttribLocation(mainShaderProgram, 'vertPosition');
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, susanPosVertexBufferObject);
gl.vertexAttribPointer(
    positionAttribLocationSusan,
    3,
    gl.FLOAT,
    gl.FALSE,
    3 * Float32Array.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT,
    0
);
gl.enableVertexAttribArray(positionAttribLocationSusan);

var texCoordAttribLocationSusan = gl.getAttribLocation(mainShaderProgram, 'vertTexCoord');
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, susanTexCoordVertexBufferObject);
gl.vertexAttribPointer(
    texCoordAttribLocationSusan,
    2,
    gl.FLOAT,
    gl.FALSE,
    2 * Float32Array.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT,
    0
);
gl.enableVertexAttribArray(texCoordAttribLocationSusan);

var normalAttribLocationSusan = gl.getAttribLocation(mainShaderProgram, 'vertNormal');
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, susanNormalBufferObject);
gl.vertexAttribPointer(
    normalAttribLocationSusan,
    3,
    gl.FLOAT,
    gl.TRUE,
    3 * Float32Array.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT,
    0
);
gl.enableVertexAttribArray(normalAttribLocationSusan);

    

var floorVertices =
[ // X, Y, Z            U, V
    -1.0, -1.0, -1.0,   1, 1,
    -1.0, -1.0, 1.0,    1, 0,
    1.0, -1.0, 1.0,     0, 0,
    1.0, -1.0, -1.0,    0, 1,
];

var floorIndices =
[
    0, 1, 2,
    0, 2, 3,
];

// Create buffer for the floor

    // PROBLEM CODE (The program renders 3 monkeys without this being here, but with it being here, the program renders nothing)

gl.useProgram(floorShaderProgram);
var floorVertexBufferObject = gl.createBuffer(); // create buffer
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, floorVertexBufferObject); // bind buffer
gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(floorVertices), gl.STATIC_DRAW); // load data into buffer

var floorIndexBufferObject = gl.createBuffer();
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, floorIndexBufferObject);
gl.bufferData(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, new Uint16Array(floorIndices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

var positionAttribLocationFloor = gl.getAttribLocation(floorShaderProgram, 'vertPosition'); // get location of attribute in program
var texCoordAttribLocationFloor = gl.getAttribLocation(floorShaderProgram, 'vertTexCoord');
gl.vertexAttribPointer(
    positionAttribLocationFloor, // attribute location
    3, // number of elements per attribute
    gl.FLOAT, // type of elements
    gl.FALSE, // normalized
    5 * Float32Array.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT, // size of an individual vertex
    0 // offset from the beginning of a single vertex to this attribute
);
gl.vertexAttribPointer(
    texCoordAttribLocationFloor, // attribute location
    2, // number of elements per attribute
    gl.FLOAT, // type of elements
    gl.FALSE, // normalized
    5 * Float32Array.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT, // size of an individual vertex
    3 * Float32Array.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT // offset from the beginning of a single vertex to this attribute
);

gl.enableVertexAttribArray(positionAttribLocationFloor);
gl.enableVertexAttribArray(texCoordAttribLocationFloor);
    // END OF PROBLEM CODE





// ------------- Create texture -------------
var susanTexture = gl.createTexture();
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, susanTexture);
gl.pixelStorei(gl.UNPACK_FLIP_Y_WEBGL, true);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);
gl.texImage2D(
    gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.RGBA,
    gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE,
    SusanImage
);
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, null);

var boxTexture = gl.createTexture();
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, boxTexture);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);

    gl.texImage2D(
    gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.RGBA,
    gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE,
    document.getElementById('crate-image')
    );
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, null);

// Tell OpenGL state machine which program should be active.
gl.useProgram(floorShaderProgram);
var floorMatWorldUniformLocation = gl.getUniformLocation(floorShaderProgram, 'mWorld');


gl.useProgram(mainShaderProgram);
var matWorldUniformLocation = gl.getUniformLocation(mainShaderProgram, 'mWorld');
var matViewUniformLocation = gl.getUniformLocation(mainShaderProgram, 'mView');
var matProjUniformLocation = gl.getUniformLocation(mainShaderProgram, 'mProj');




var worldMatrix = new Float32Array(16);
var viewMatrix = new Float32Array(16);
var projMatrix = new Float32Array(16);
mat4.identity(worldMatrix);
mat4.lookAt(viewMatrix, [0, 0, -8], [0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0]);
mat4.perspective(projMatrix, glMatrix.toRadian(45), canvas.width / canvas.height, 0.1, 1000.0);

gl.useProgram(floorShaderProgram);
gl.uniformMatrix4fv(floorMatWorldUniformLocation, gl.FALSE, worldMatrix);
gl.useProgram(mainShaderProgram);
gl.uniformMatrix4fv(matWorldUniformLocation, gl.FALSE, worldMatrix);
gl.uniformMatrix4fv(matViewUniformLocation, gl.FALSE, viewMatrix);
gl.uniformMatrix4fv(matProjUniformLocation, gl.FALSE, projMatrix);

var xRotationMatrix = new Float32Array(16);
var yRotationMatrix = new Float32Array(16);

var objects = [
    { worldMatrix: mat4.create(), coord: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0], type: 'susan' }, // type doesn't do anything yet
    { worldMatrix: mat4.create(), coord: [-3.0, -3.0, 5.0], type: 'susan' },
    { worldMatrix: mat4.create(), coord: [3.0, -3.0, 5.0], type: 'susan' },
    { worldMatrix: mat4.create(), coord: [0.0, -1.0, 0.0], type: 'floor' }
];


// ------------- Lighting information -------------
gl.useProgram(mainShaderProgram);
var ambientUniformLocation = gl.getUniformLocation(mainShaderProgram, 'ambientLightIntensity');
var sunlightDirUniformLocation = gl.getUniformLocation(mainShaderProgram, 'sunlightDirection');
var sunlightIntUniformLocation = gl.getUniformLocation(mainShaderProgram, 'sunlightIntensity');

gl.uniform3f(ambientUniformLocation, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2);
gl.uniform3f(sunlightDirUniformLocation, 3.0, 4.0, -2.0);
gl.uniform3f(sunlightIntUniformLocation, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9);


// ------------- Main loop -------------

var identityMatrix = new Float32Array(16);
mat4.identity(identityMatrix);
var angle = 0;
var loop = function () {
    gl.clearColor(0.75, 0.85, 0.8, 1.0);
    gl.clear(gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    angle = performance.now() / 1000 / 6 * 2 * Math.PI;

    index = 0;
    // Render objects
    for (obj of objects){
        index += 1;
        if (index == 1){ // susan
            mat4.identity(obj.worldMatrix);
            mat4.rotate(yRotationMatrix, obj.worldMatrix, angle, [0, 1, 0]);
            mat4.rotate(xRotationMatrix, obj.worldMatrix, angle / 4, [1, 0, 0]);
            mat4.mul(obj.worldMatrix, yRotationMatrix, xRotationMatrix);


            gl.useProgram(mainShaderProgram);
            gl.uniformMatrix4fv(matWorldUniformLocation, gl.FALSE, obj.worldMatrix);
            gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, susanTexture);
            gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE0);

            gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, susanIndices.length, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
        }
        else if (index == 2){ // susan
            obj.worldMatrix[12] = obj.coord[0]; // x
            obj.worldMatrix[13] = obj.coord[1]; // y
            obj.worldMatrix[14] = obj.coord[2]; // z

            gl.useProgram(mainShaderProgram);
            gl.uniformMatrix4fv(matWorldUniformLocation, gl.FALSE, obj.worldMatrix);
            gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, susanTexture);
            gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE0);

            gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, susanIndices.length, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
        }
        else if (index == 3) { // susan
            obj.worldMatrix[12] = obj.coord[0]; // x
            obj.worldMatrix[13] = obj.coord[1]; // y
            obj.worldMatrix[14] = obj.coord[2]; // z

            gl.useProgram(mainShaderProgram);
            gl.uniformMatrix4fv(matWorldUniformLocation, gl.FALSE, obj.worldMatrix);
            gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, boxTexture);
            gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE0);

            gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, susanIndices.length, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
        }
        else if (index == 4) { // floor
            obj.worldMatrix[12] = obj.coord[0]; // x
            obj.worldMatrix[13] = obj.coord[1]; // y
            obj.worldMatrix[14] = obj.coord[2]; // z

            gl.useProgram(floorShaderProgram);
            gl.uniformMatrix4fv(floorMatWorldUniformLocation, gl.FALSE, obj.worldMatrix);
            gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, boxTexture);
            gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE0);
            
            gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, floorIndices.length, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
        }


        
    }

    index = 0;

    requestAnimationFrame(loop);

    };


requestAnimationFrame(loop);
```

};

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vertex attribute pointers are a global state, when you define your plane geometry buffer you (partially) override the pointers that you setup previously for the susan mesh. To further clarify on this, the attribute locations that you query from the shader are not unique, they're merely the *index of the vertex attribute* so `positionAttribLocationSusan` may very well be identical to `positionAttribLocationFloor`, an attribute location is simply an integer between 0 and [`MAX_VERTEX_ATTRIBS`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61584985/is-webgl-max-vertex-attribs-defined-per-shader-or-is-it-defined-as-a-global-limi), a call to `vertexAttribPointer` associates the most recently bound `ARRAY_BUFFER` with a global vertex attribute unit(0-`MAX_VERTEX_ATTRIBS`), the shader you queried that location from is not taken into account.

That means that if you want to draw various geometry from various buffers you need to bind the buffer, setup the attribute pointers and enable/disable the attributes before each draw call (in case they changed), this process can be streamlined by using [VAOs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGLVertexArrayObject).

So for your code that means that in your rendering loop you want to:

```
bind susan position buffer
set position attribute pointer
bind susan normal buffer
set normal attribute pointer
[repeat for other susan attributes]
(ensure that bound (and only bound) attributes are enabled)
bind susan shader program
set static uniforms
for each susan object
  set object specific uniforms
  call draw

bind floor position buffer
set position attribute pointer
[repeat for other floor attributes]
(ensure that bound (and only bound) attributes are enabled)
bind floor shader program
set floor shader uniforms
call draw
```

PS: you don't have to rebind the shader program before each draw call, which is factored in in my provided pseudocode